# Python: How to print with UTF-8 characters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, utf-8

I have been trying for hours to solve this UTF-8 issue in Python 2.7.6.

I have a list of string with UTF-8 characters, like this:

```
findings=['Quimica Geral e Tecnol\xf3gica I', 'Quimica Geral e Tecnol\xf3gica II', '\xc1lgebra Linear']
```

I am trying to print the strings:

```
for finding in findings:
      print finding
```

The output is:

```
Quimica Geral e Tecnolgica I
Quimica Geral e Tecnolgica II
lgebra Linear
```

I also tried this:

```
for finding in findings:
      print( "%s"%(finding))
```

and I got the same output.

If I try to save in file:

```
file = open("teste.txt", "w")
for finding in findings:
  file.write("%s\n" % finding)
file.close()
```

It works and the output is (please note the latin characters - accents):

```
Quimica Geral e Tecnológica I
Quimica Geral e Tecnológica II
Álgebra Linear
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you don't get any errors from Python, chances are the problem is with your console/terminal. How are you running Python, on what? (`cmd` running on Windows? Which Windows? What code page? Or Linux? Which Linux, connected how? GUI or plain console? What locale? Or OSX? Terminal or some sort of GUI?)

Comment: @tripleee I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 and using Spyder. You are right (I havent thought about this), When I run in the Terminal, I het something like "Quimica Geral e Tecnol?gica I" or "?lgebra Linear?" So this means that the problem is with the GUI? Is my code correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your strings to unicode with `unicode` function and use [`unicode-escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) ( Produce a string that is suitable as Unicode literal in Python source code )as your encodeing :

```
>>> for i in findings :
...    print unicode(i,'unicode-escape')
... 
 Quimica Geral e Tecnológica I
 Quimica Geral e Tecnológica II
 Álgebra Linear
```

Added : The I/O system is built as a series of layers and when you open a file for writing it use `io.TextIOWrapper` layer that is a text-handling layer that encodes and decodes Unicode automatically .

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan The I/O system is built as a series of layers and what you open a file for writing it use `io.TextIOWrapper` layer that is a text-handling layer that encodes and decodes Unicode.automatically